# Python LDAP old password still working

Tags: python, authentication, ldap

I have the LDAP python module installed to authorise logins via active directory, but if I change the password, the new and the old one work together.  Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect that it is active directory who is caching the credentials -at least for some time after the change- ; have a look at [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=906305).